# Oracle - Divide a string based on total length of string

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle, select

I have a non standardized data in one of the column and I need to be splitting the data into 3 parts.
there is no specific requirement on length each column should have. It's just that the entire data to be split into 3

Input Data 01 : test , test ,test/test
Input data 02: Test; test,test\testing123data123datadatatawerr

OutPut 01:  Col1=test   Col2= test,test  Col3=/test
Output 02:  Col1= Test; col2= test,test  col3=\testing123data123datadatatawerr

Is there a way to take the total length and based on that divide into 3 parts.
Concatenating of split data  I need to get the entire string back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to be splitting the data into 3 parts. there is no specific requirement on length each column should have

The simplest approach is to use `substr()`:

```
select
    substr(col, 1, 1) col1,
    substr(col, 2, 1) col2
    substr(col, 3)    col3
from mytable
```

The first two columns contain one character each, starting from the beginning of the string; the last column contains the reminder. This guarantees that each column will be fed (provided that the string is at least 3 characters).

On the other hand if you want to split in three parts whose length is close to equal, you can do:

```
select
    substr(col, 1, round(length(col) / 3)) col1,
    substr(col, 1 + round(length(col) / 3), round(length(col) / 3)) col2
    substr(col, 1 + 2 * round(length(col) / 3))    col3
from mytable
```

Comment: It does Work,  but the Characters are split to different columns. Is there a way to split based on special characters into 1 or 2 or 3 columns based on their availability.                        
    select
    substr('test , test , test/ test', 1, round(length('test , test , test/test') / 3)) col1,
    substr('test , test , test/test', 1 + round(length('test , test , test/test') / 3), round(length('test , test ,test/test') / 3)) col2,
    substr('test , test , test/test', 1 + 2 * round(length('test ,  test ,test/test') / 3))    col3
from dual

Comment: @user2815115: this is a different question than the one your originally asked. You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this.